# Can any one tell based on the NewRelic performance stats where do you think the app needs to be optimized

Tags: newrelic

Can any one take a look at the NewRelic performance stats in the image and tell me which part of the application should be optimized to yield max benefits in terms of performance? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you tell which stack are you using. 
In the bottom part of the page you can visualize the slowest requests. Click in one of them, then you will have a detailed stack trace: # of requests, stack deadlocks and time.